# android Download Manager is not storing files on External SD card and it fails executing request with status 403 on Android PIE OS9

Tags: android, image, android-download-manager, android-external-storage, download-manager

I am downloading files using Android's Download Manager and storing the files on removeable SD Card. It is working on Android OS6 Marshmallow and Android OS8 Oreo but NOT working on Android OS9 PIE.
`setDestinationURI()` is being used to store files on removable SD Card.

```
private fun setExternalStorageDir() {
val arrayOfFiles = getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) //as per official documentation
parentDirectory = if (arrayOfFiles.size > 1 && arrayOfFiles[0] != null && arrayOfFiles[1] != null)
arrayOfFiles[1].toString() //External Storage Dir Path being retrieved successfully
else if (arrayOfFiles.size == 1 && arrayOfFiles[0] != null)
arrayOfFiles[0].toString() //Internal Storage being treated as External Storage by Android
else
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS //Internal Storage Download Folder
}

//Request Builder Code. Request is being sucessfully executed in OS 6 and 8 respectively

val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri).apply {
setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
setTitle("Image Downloading")
setNotificationVisibility(VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)

setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(File("$parentDirectory/sampleImage.png")))
}

private val onDownloadComplete = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
val reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
val query = DownloadManager.Query()
query.setFilterById(reference)
val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)
cursor.moveToFirst()
val statusIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
val status = cursor.getInt(statusIndex)

if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {

} else if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
Log.e("DOWNLOAD BROADCAST", "Download failed")
val reasonIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)
val reason = cursor.getInt(reasonIndex)
Log.e("DOWNLOAD BROADCAST", reason.toString())
}
}
}
```

DownloadManager fails executing request on Android PIE OS9 with status 403

PS: Min SDK 21, Targetted 29. Runtime Permissions are handled.

**W/DownloadManager: [37] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: Permission denied"**

Comment: What is the value of `parentDirectory` during your run?

Comment: What does 403 mean?

Comment: I wonder if the download manager can store files on microSD card using Marshmellow and Oreo. Hard to believe.

Comment: `else
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS //Internal Storage Download Folder`. No That is nothing.

Comment: `parentDirectory = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package/files //Embedded Storage`

`parentDirectory = /storage/0000-EEA3/Android/data/package/files //SD Card`

Comment: Unable to identify exactly what 403 means in terms of Download Manager specifically, its using http status code may be 403 Forbidden?

Comment: Well it does storing on microSD card, verified on different devices running Marshmallow and Oreo

Comment: **W/DownloadManager: [37] Stop requested with status FILE_ERROR: Failed to generate filename: java.io.IOException: Permission denied**

Comment: @ShoaibMushtaq Any Solution you found?

Comment: @UmairIqbal, No solution found yet for Android Pie and I have not even tried it.